# Issue with disabled textboxes being re-enabled on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net

forgive me, but I'm still new to the whole programming thing and I've been unable to find a more specific / straightforward answer to my query.

I have a form that I've built in asp.net C# that pulls data from a database.  A stored procedure runs and auto-populates a series of textboxes if it finds anything - a user's name, email, phone number, etc. Populated fields are then disabled, so the user can't change what's been brought through; empty fields remain enabled for the user to complete if required.

However, when the user submits the form - and if it fails validation - previously disabled fields (those with data) are being enabled, allowing the user to overwrite them if they wanted - but I need to prevent this from happening; is there anyway to keep those fields that were disabled by my original data being found from being re-enabled on return?

I'm disabling the fields on a button-click event.  The fields are being disabled on page-load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Page.Title = title;
        Literal formHeader = (Literal)this.Master.FindControl("formHeader");
        formHeader.Text = "Travel Booking Request";




    if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
            { 
              Load_FormDetails();
              Load_SeatingPreference();
              Load_UserResponses();
              Load_UndergroundTravelZones();

            }
        }
protected void Load_FormDetails()
    {
            string userName = "";
            string userPhone = "";
            string userTitle = "";
            string userEmail = "";
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> userDetails = Class1.GetUserDetails();
            var name = userDetails.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "UserDisplayName").Select(kvp => kvp.Value).First();
            userName = name.ToString();
            var phone = userDetails.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "UserLandline").Select(kvp => kvp.Value).First();
            userPhone = phone.ToString();
            var jobtitle = userDetails.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "UserJobTitle").Select(kvp => kvp.Value).First();
            userTitle = jobtitle.ToString();
            var email = userDetails.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "UserEmail").Select(kvp => kvp.Value).First();
            userEmail = email.ToString();
            txtUserName.Text = userName;

            if (txtUserName.Text != "")
            {
                txtUserName.Enabled = "false";
            }
            txtUserPhoneNumber.Text = userPhone;
            if (txtUserPhoneNumber.Text != "")
            {
                txtUserPhoneNumber.Enabled = "false";
            }
            txtUserJobTitle.Text = userTitle;
            if (txtUserJobTitle.Text != "")
            {
                pfptxtUserJobTitle.Enabled = "false";
            }
            txtUserEmail.Text = userEmail;
            if (txtUserEmail.Text != "")
            {
                txtUserEmail.Enabled = "false";
            }
        }
```

Comment: where are you adding that `enabled=false` , paste some code

Comment: Sorry - my bad. I've edited my initial post to include code.

Comment: When you want to enable your `TextBox` ?

Comment: I want it enabled if it doesn't return data from the DB (so if, for example, there's no phone number stored in the DB) - this is so when the user submits the form, they can complete the missing (blank) fields and that data can be capture for next time.  I don't want the fields enabled if that data already exists in the DB and has been pulled through - I don't want my user to update already existing data in those fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your textbox defination in .aspx page add Readonly = true or add enabled = false.

It will make textbox disabled permanantly

Comment: I've already tried this, but it still gives me my issue in reverse - if I disabled them in the aspx file then enable them if blank data is brought through from the DB, they're re-disabled if the page fails validation on submit. Basically I only want the fields to be disabled if they contain data brought through from the DB. If the DB can't populate a field (i.e. there's no phone number stored), then I want the user to be able to type their number in that field. It's fine until I submit and the page fails validation - on return, the page loads back to it's original state.

Comment: I think there is some condition missing in page load.. have you used ispostback property correctly?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, yes I have - the method that's loading (Load_FormDetails) is being loaded on page-load - I've edited the code above to show where it's being called in the first instance.

Comment: In load formdetails function.. this function will be called for the first time only and not for the loading of page because of submit button click. So on button click it will reset everything again. Add textbox disable conditions out of the !ispostback loop.

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner, but things have been manic here.  Thanks Ram, your solution to add the conditions outside of the !ispostback worked.  :)

Comment: Cheers happy coding :)